# What is the correct way to convert a has_and_belongs_to_many table into Arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am translating a complex PostgreSQL string into Arel and would like to know what is the correct way to 'arelize' a `has_and_belongs_to_many` table. For example here are the related models:

```
class Release < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :vulnerabilities
end

class Vulnerability < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :releases
end
```

The class setup creates a table called `releases_vulnerabilities` but I can't seem to convert it to arel. I've tried in my rails console `Release_Vulnerability.arel_table` and then I tried `Arel::Table.new(:releases_vulnerabilities)` but the second implementation doesn't allow me to query the associated foreign keys. What is the correct way to convert this table into arel?

Comment: Why not use `has_many: releases, through: assembly_parts`? is there really a good reason to not create the AssemblyPart model? that would allow you to easily turn everything into arel. Also, why do you think you need arel in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "the second implementation doesn't allow me to query the associated foreign keys"?

Comment: Why do you want to 'arelize' it in the first place? Arel is a really unstable private api that get's changed without notice on a Rails upgrade.

Comment: @Iceman, I've been told to use it for consistency from my teammates.

Comment: @chumakoff, I meant something like releases_vulnerabilities[:vulnerability_id]

Comment: @radha, I just needed to add the join model and then convert it to arel. I'm limited to what I can change without breaking anything so I can't exactly change the associations.

Comment: I am almost sure you can do that. Why not? `arel_table = Arel::Table.new(:releases_vulnerabilities)` Now you can access any field: `arel_table[:vulnerability_id]`. If it doesn't work for you, show your code and the error it throws.

Comment: @chumakoff I got it to work once the model was added. And then I was able to convert it to arel. Thanks.

Comment: @DanRubio associations wont change, and you if you try to create an arel table without an AR model it will give you a warning. You used to be able to do this, Arel::Table.new('table_name') without problems, but now it will warn you.

Answer (score 0):

you can perfectly change this

```
class Release < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :vulnerabilities
end

class Vulnerability < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :releases
end
```

into this

```
class Release < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :vulnerabilities
  has_many :vulnerabilities, through: :release_vulnerabilities
end

class ReleaseVulnerabilities < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vulnerability
  belongs_to :release
end

class Vulnerability < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :release_vulnerabilities
  has_many :releases, through: :release_vulnerabilities
end
```

And you will not lose any relations, you dont even need to update the code since @vulnerability.releases, still works, if you look at both queries you will see its a join in both cases.
Now about the ideas to "arielize" have a look at [this conversion I did](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/pull/829/files)